# Bind Button Text property in Avalonia

Tags: c#, binding, avaloniaui

In my .axaml file I have next markup:

```
<Button Text="{Binding SwitchWorkDayState, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

And after build project get error:

> AVLN:0004 Unable to resolve suitable regular or attached property Text
> on type Avalonia.Controls:Avalonia.Controls.Button

Binding rules from documentation match in markup. Property `SwitchWorkDayState` has type `string` and presents in DataContext (ViewModel class).

Anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, after avalonia plugins installation I noticed, that property Text not exists for button. Digging internet for replacement I found that instead should be used property Content:

```
<Button Content="{Binding SwitchWorkDayState, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

I strongly recommend to install plugins for your IDE. That's how it looks for visual studio:

[image]